# Get Data from JSON file into jQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, datatables

I am trying to adding add data from a JSON file that I generated from Django script.

This is the format of JSON file:

```
[
{
    "6": "yo1",
    "1": "2019-04-04",
    "4": "yo1",
    "3": "yo1",
    "2": "yo1",
    "5": "yo1"
},
{
    "6": "yo2",
    "1": "2019-04-08",
    "4": "yo2",
    "3": "yo2",
    "2": "yo2",
    "5": "yo2"
}
]
```

JavaScript:

```
let url = `/api/?site=${filters.site_filter}&sd=${filters.sd}&ed=${filters.ed}&report_type=yo`;

 $.getJSON(url, function(data) {data.forEach(d => {
        console.log(data);
        $('#video_data').DataTable( {
            "ajax": allData
            columns: [
            { title: "1" },
            { title: "2" },
            { title: "3" },
            { title: "4" },
            { title: "5" },
            { title: "6" }
            ]
        } );
    })
})
```

HTML Code:

```
<table border="1" id="video_data">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Site</th>
                    <th>Page Type</th>
                    <th>Device Type</th>
                    <th>Video Player Name</th>
                    <th>AB Test</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The result of this only gives me a `Loading` message and also I am getting this error every time I load the page: `DataTables warning: table id=video_data - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3`

I am not sure what I a, doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `allData`?

Comment: Get rid of the `forEach`. You are initializing the plugin every iteration of that loop. Also not needing "ajax" option if you do your own request

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple things that look wrong with this.

The first parameter of `.getJSON` should be the path to the json file. From the looks of it, `allData` does not seem to be a path.

Also, you are looping through each item from the `getJson` response and initializing your data table again and again.

Lastly, to initialize the table with a dataset, use the property `data` and not `ajax`. Should look something like this:

```
var url = 'path/to/json/file.json';
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  $('#video_data').DataTable({
    data: data
  });
})
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I am getting the `DataTables warning: table id=video_data - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4` error